# Windows Phone 8 Navigate back to same page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

Does anyone know if the `NavigationService.Navigate` has any restrictions or does not call a pages default constructor when trying to navigate back to itself?   So lets say I am on MainPage.xaml and I do some stuff and want to redirect back to itself using `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));`.  I have that now and put a break point in the default constructor and it never gets hit when I try to navigate the page back to itself.

EDIT:  From my testing it seems like it caches itself.  I tested this theory by putting a querystring variable to my navigation, `"/MainPage.xaml?z=" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()` and it hit the constructor that way but not by just navigating back to just "MainPage.xaml".

Answer (score 2):

This may help you.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/MainPage.xaml?Refresh=true&random={0}", Guid.NewGuid()), UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: That is basically what I ended up doing initially to test the theory out.  I put the `DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()` as a querystring value and the page refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using NavigationService.navigate(...), it will create a new page and the constructor will be called  because it is creating a new object but if the call is made like

> NavigationService.goback()

it will go back and call the onNavigated() method.

To explain it more clearly you can think that you have three pages A,B,C and on A you used navigate(to B) and this will create B page. Let us assume that you used another navigate method and this will create another page C. Now if you use

- navigate(to A) method, the page stack will be A-B-C-A and goBack() will pop pages from the stack
- goBack() method, the page stack will be A-B and another goback() will pop another page resulting in only A page.

A constructor is called only once when it is created and the rest of times only onNavigated() method will be called.

Comment: Yeah, it seems as long as you call the exact same page, the exact same way the constructor is only called once.  Once I added a randomized querystring variable, the constructor was called each time I hit the same page.

Comment: NO. It wont differ with query strings. Please show us more code to say what is happening.

Comment: It absolutely did.  I did various tests and going to MainPage.xaml than to another page and than back to MainPage.xaml called the constructor.  Now when I tried to redirect MainPage.xaml back to itself, no querystrings, it didn't call the constructor nor reload the page.  It did hit the OnNavigatedTo but didn't refresh the content on the screen.  It was only when I added a randomized querystring variable that it refreshed the content.  My testing is saying otherwise unless my phone is quirky.  It's a nokia lumina 520.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to hit the Constructor? There are alternatives. I do not do anything in the constructor. All I do is bind a event handler for Load and do all the initialization in the Load event handler. Also, there is OnNavigateTo() which gets hit when you use NavigationService.Navigate().

If you have OnNavigateTo and Load in one code-behind, OnNavigateTo gets hit first and then the Load.

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Basically I wanted all of the data and the page to reload.  I have a bunch of pivot items with long list selectors.  I was using the contnexmenu to be able to delete specific items.  I tried approaches such as doing the .ItemSource.Remove(object) to get rid of it on the page and also updating the layout but the content itself didn't refresh.  Than I tried just navigating back to itself so the content data would refresh.  That didn't happen until I added a query string.  I come from the web world and over the past few months started diving into the mobile side, android and windows, so I may...

Comment: be taking more of a web style approach than the mobile/desktop style approach.

Comment: iCobot, the approach should be to do a delete which would take the record off the database, and then reload the data from the datasource. This will refresh the list.

Comment: That was the approach I initially took.  I deleted the file from storage.  I than updated the values stored in the ApplicationSettings.  I than re-set to make sure the data was to be re-loaded with a boolean flag.  Data still showed and even showed after I shut down the debugger and restarted.

Comment: Did you confirm whether the file got deleted from Isolated Storage? You can do that with the Isolated Storage Explorer with comes with Windows Phone Power Tools.